# c#, MVVM, редактирование модели в отдельном окне

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

У меня имеется модель

```
public class Student : NotificationObject
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return SecondName + " " + Name[0] + ". " + MiddleName[0] + "."; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _secondName;
    public string SecondName
    {
        get { return _secondName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _secondName != value)
            {
                _secondName = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SecondName));
            }
        }
    }

    private string _middleName;
    public string MiddleName
    {
        get { return _middleName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _middleName != value)
            {
                _middleName = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MiddleName));
            }
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<BooleanWrapper> _attendance;
    public ObservableCollection<BooleanWrapper> Attendance
    {
        get { return _attendance; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && _attendance != value)
            {
                _attendance = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Attendance));
            }
        }
    }

    private Student(){ }

    public Student(string Name, string SecondName, string MiddleName)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.SecondName = SecondName;
        this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
        Attendance = new ObservableCollection<BooleanWrapper>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

В ходе работы приложения появляется необходимость создания\добавления объектов модели. Это делаю через специальную пару View-ViewModel.

Проблема в том, что не могу понять как правильно забиндиться при редактировании объекта модели в ViewModel. Если раньше использовал метод Set() из ViewModelBase, то здесь привязки (как я думаю) необходимо осуществить к свойствам объекта модели (а исходя из сигнатуры Set свойства нельзя передавать с ключевым словом ref).
Получается нужно сделать что-то вроде такого?

```
public string Name
    {
        get { return Student.Name; }
        set
        {
            Student.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
```

Если это так, то тогда каким образом можно уведомить контрол из предыдущего View (в котором представлена коллекция объектов модели) об изменении свойства FullName? 
Думаю, что прописывать такое не совсем правильно:

```
//Student.cs
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null && _name != value)
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }
}

private string _secondName;
public string SecondName
{
    get { return _secondName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null && _secondName != value)
        {
            _secondName = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SecondName));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }
}

private string _middleName;
public string MiddleName
{
    get { return _middleName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null && _middleName != value)
        {
            _middleName = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MiddleName));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А чего в этом неправильного?

Comment: Ну, я думаю, что 2 одинаковые строки, отличающиеся лишь названием свойства, можно как-то в одну преобразовать.

Comment: Нет. Да и нет ничего страшного в этом.